# Python - Removing multiple spaces between word and dot

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I am trying to remove the spaces between sentence ending word and dot.

```
text = 'some sentence     .'
```

What I have tried so far:

```
import re

line = 'some sentence     .'
re.sub('\s+(\.)', '', line)
```

But it removes the dot as well. Desired output would be like that

```
some sentence.
```

Comment: You have to use the group in the replacement instead of an empty string `r"\1"`

Answer (score 0):

try replace your regex with this `\s{2,}`